# Connect links to office 365 app launcher

Tags: office-365

I would like make a link to a specific SharePoint site in all users' app launcher or under My Apps. Is this possible without involving Azure?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this answers your question:

http://blogs.office.com/2014/10/16/organize-office-365-new-app-launcher-2/

> Q. Will I have the pin/ un-pin capability?
>
> A. Yes, but only customers with Exchange will have the ability to pin and un-pin at this time.

Comment: Not entirely. What i would like to do is something more like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/connect-your-app-to-o365-app-launcher 
But instead of an app just a simple link to a SPO site.